# How do I open a blank new file in a split in Vim?

Tags: vim

Must be something super obvious, but I can't figure out, and Google is not helping out either.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

```
:help new
:help vnew
```

should bring you on course.

you will have a new buffer then, obviously. that buffer becomes a file only if you `:w`  it to the disk.

Comment: And `:set splitright` puts the new split on the right. Awesome, thanks

Comment: Also `:set splitbelow` is the corresponding command to make the new split appear on the bottom when splitting horizontally.

Answer (score 58):

another way is to do a `<CTRL + W> n` in normal mode. [This will create a new split](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/54157).

EDIT:

You can also do `<CTRL + W> v` in normal mode to create a vertical split (the previous one will do a horizontal split.

And just to be complete, you move to the different splits by doing `<CTRL + W> <direction>` with the direction being any `h`, `j`, `k`, or `l`

To close a buffer, do `<CTRL + W> q`

Comment: fyi: these open the current buffer in a new split, not a new file in a new split.

Comment: For me, `Ctrl+w n` opens a split with a new buffer, but `Ctrl+w v` just splits the current buffer.  Strange.

Comment: if you're looking to create a vertical split with a new file, check out this question/answer
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/vertical-equivalent-of-controlw-n

Comment: note that `:split <filename>` would open/edit a file in splitwindow.

Answer (score 4):

```
vim myfile.txt  # open one file in one window
:buffers        " shows one buffer with "myfile.txt" in it
:sp             " create split window; we now have one buffer with two windows.
:e newfile.txt  " create new buffer with new filename in first window
:buffers        " shows two buffers (myfile.txt & newfile.txt), each in own window
```

This is a good link: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching

Answer (score 0):

I used the Vim menu under File - Split Open.  You will have to give a name for your new blank file though.

Comment: Vim has a menu?

Comment: gvim or macvim are able to display a menu, yes. what did you expect? :)

Comment: It seems that :sp also can work -- for those not using the gvim version.